# NetworkBoundResource helper class without Room

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

When I tried to implements the `NetworkBoundResource` and `Resource` helper class for the Room Db and Retrofit, it works perfect. However, I need to implement the Search Result from RESTful using **Retrofit only without Room**. The `Resources` class is good and I dont need to change it. What I want to do is try to remove db source inside this class.

```
public abstract class NetworkBoundResource<ResultType, RequestType> {
  private final AppExecutors appExecutors;

  private final MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();

  @MainThread
  public NetworkBoundResource(AppExecutors appExecutors) {
    this.appExecutors = appExecutors;
    result.setValue(Resource.loading(null));
    LiveData<ResultType> dbSource = loadFromDb();
    result.addSource(dbSource, data -> {
      result.removeSource(dbSource);
      if (shouldFetch(data)) {
        fetchFromNetwork(dbSource);
      } else {
        result.addSource(dbSource, newData -> setValue(Resource.success(newData)));
      }
    });
  }

  @MainThread
  private void setValue(Resource<ResultType> newValue) {
    if (!Objects.equals(result.getValue(), newValue)) {
      result.setValue(newValue);
    }
  }

  private void fetchFromNetwork(final LiveData<ResultType> dbSource) {
    LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>> apiResponse = createCall();
    // we re-attach dbSource as a new source, it will dispatch its latest value quickly
    result.addSource(dbSource, newData -> setValue(Resource.loading(newData)));
    result.addSource(apiResponse, response -> {
      result.removeSource(apiResponse);
      result.removeSource(dbSource);
      //noinspection ConstantConditions
      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        appExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
          saveCallResult(processResponse(response));
          appExecutors.mainThread().execute(() ->
              // we specially request a new live data,
              // otherwise we will get immediately last cached value,
              // which may not be updated with latest results received from network.
              result.addSource(loadFromDb(),
                  newData -> setValue(Resource.success(newData)))
          );
        });
      } else {
        onFetchFailed();
        result.addSource(dbSource,
            newData -> setValue(Resource.error(response.errorMessage, newData)));
      }
    });
  }

  protected void onFetchFailed() {
  }

  public LiveData<Resource<ResultType>> asLiveData() {
    return result;
  }

  @WorkerThread
  protected RequestType processResponse(ApiResponse<RequestType> response) {
    return response.body;
  }

  @WorkerThread
  protected abstract void saveCallResult(@NonNull RequestType item);

  @MainThread
  protected abstract boolean shouldFetch(@Nullable ResultType data);

  @NonNull
  @MainThread
  protected abstract LiveData<ResultType> loadFromDb();

  @NonNull
  @MainThread
  protected abstract LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>> createCall();
}
```

Comment: Have you  tried to leave `NetworkBoundResource`  as it is and you can toggle the behavior with in the two protected methods `saveCallResult()` and  `loadFromDb()` and make `shouldFetch()` always return true?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that any loaded data have to go through the database first, then loading it from the database to the UI, as `NetworkBoundResource` does. Consequently, What I did is to decouple the persistent database and create a temporary field to load from.

For example if I wanted to edit the [original](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/2e09898630783bf863ddd82f1c30817da9a2fe32/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/RepoRepository.java#L179-L229) search method, I would suggest:

```
public LiveData<Resource<List<Repo>>> search(String query) {
    return new NetworkBoundResource<List<Repo>, RepoSearchResponse>(appExecutors) {

        // Temp ResultType
        private List<Repo> resultsDb;

        @Override
        protected void saveCallResult(@NonNull RepoSearchResponse item) {
            // if you don't care about order
            resultsDb = item.getItems();
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean shouldFetch(@Nullable List<Repo> data) {
            // always fetch.
            return true;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected LiveData<List<Repo>> loadFromDb() {
            if (resultsDb == null) {
                return AbsentLiveData.create();
            }else {
                return new LiveData<List<Repo>>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onActive() {
                        super.onActive();
                        setValue(resultsDb);
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected LiveData<ApiResponse<RepoSearchResponse>> createCall() {
            return githubService.searchRepos(query);
        }

        @Override
        protected RepoSearchResponse processResponse(ApiResponse<RepoSearchResponse> response) {
            RepoSearchResponse body = response.body;
            if (body != null) {
                body.setNextPage(response.getNextPage());
            }
            return body;
        }
    }.asLiveData();
}
```

I ran it and it works.

**Edit:** 
I made another simpler class to handle that (There is another answer here by Daniel Wilson has more feature and is updated).

However, this class has no dependencies and is converted to the basics to make fetch response only:

```
abstract class NetworkBoundResource<RequestType> {

    private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<RequestType>>()

    init {
        setValue(Resource.loading(null))
        fetchFromNetwork()
    }

    @MainThread
    private fun setValue(newValue: Resource<RequestType>) {
        if (result.value != newValue) {
            result.value = newValue
        }
    }

    private fun fetchFromNetwork() {
        val apiResponse = createCall()
        result.addSource(apiResponse) { response ->
            result.removeSource(apiResponse)

            when (response) {
                is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                        setValue(Resource.success(processResponse(response)))
                }

                is ApiErrorResponse -> {
                    onFetchFailed()
                    setValue(Resource.error(response.errorMessage, null))

                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected fun onFetchFailed() {
    }

    fun asLiveData() = result as LiveData<Resource<RequestType>>

    @WorkerThread
    protected open fun processResponse(response: ApiSuccessResponse<RequestType>) = response.body

    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun createCall(): LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>>
}
```

So when using it, only one method could be implemented `createCall()`:

```
fun login(email: String, password: String) = object : NetworkBoundResource<Envelope<User>>() {
    override fun createCall() = api.login(email, password)
}.asLiveData()
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Can you explain to me the way you should write the processResponse- block?

Comment: Yeah bypassing room with the Network Bound Resource is kind of a hack. I'd like to see if I can come up with a better way

Comment: Is there any other solution possible?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my attempt after a long while!

```
abstract class NetworkOnlyResource<ResultType, RequestType>
@MainThread constructor(private val appExecutors: AppExecutors) {

    private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>>() //List<Repo>
    private val request = MediatorLiveData<Resource<RequestType>>() //RepoSearchResponse

    init {
        result.value = Resource.loading(null)
        fetchFromNetwork()
    }

    @MainThread
    private fun setResultValue(newValue: Resource<ResultType>) {
        if (result.value != newValue) {
            result.value = newValue
        }
    }

    private fun fetchFromNetwork() {
        val apiResponse = createCall()

        result.addSource(apiResponse) { response ->
            result.removeSource(apiResponse)

            response?.let {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    appExecutors.diskIO().execute({
                        val requestType = processResponse(response)
                        val resultType = processResult(requestType)
                        appExecutors.mainThread().execute({
                            setResultValue(Resource.success(resultType))
                        }
                        )
                    })
                } else {

                    val errorMessage = when (response.errorThrowable) {
                        is HttpException -> "An error has occurred: ${response.errorThrowable.code()} Please try again."
                        is SocketTimeoutException -> "A timeout error has occurred, please check your internet connection and try again"
                        is IOException -> "An IO error has occurred, most likely a network issue. Please check your internet connection and try again"
                        is UnauthorizedCredentialsException -> "This user name or password is not recognized"
                        else -> {
                            response.errorMessage
                        }
                    }

                    Timber.e(errorMessage)

                    errorMessage?.let {
                        val requestType = processResponse(response)
                        val resultType = processResult(requestType)
                        setResultValue(Resource.error(errorMessage, resultType, response.errorThrowable))
                    }

                    onFetchFailed()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected open fun onFetchFailed() {}

    fun asLiveData() = result as LiveData<Resource<ResultType>>

    @WorkerThread
    protected open fun processResponse(response: ApiResponse<RequestType>) = response.body

    @WorkerThread
    protected abstract fun processResult(item: RequestType?): ResultType?

    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun createCall(): LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>>
}
```

The `processResult()` function allows you to transform a successful RequestType into a ResultType. It seems to work for me but would love any feedback from someone that knows what they are doing :)

Fyi Yigit has since updated the NetworkBoundResource with better error handling which should also work here in the not-successful 'else' statement.

Comment: I guess `AppExecutors` is not needed here anymore, is it?
I reached a similar implementation and updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version which I wrote sometime back:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData
import android.support.annotation.MainThread

/**
 * A generic class to send loading event up-stream when fetching data
 * only from network.
 *
 * @param <RequestType>
</RequestType></ResultType> */
abstract class NetworkResource<RequestType> @MainThread constructor() {

    /**
     * The final result LiveData
     */
    private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<RequestType>>()

    init {
        // Send loading state to UI
        result.value = Resource.loading()
        fetchFromNetwork()
    }

    /**
     * Fetch the data from network and then send it upstream to UI.
     */
    private fun fetchFromNetwork() {
        val apiResponse = createCall()
        // Make the network call
        result.addSource(apiResponse) { response ->
            result.removeSource(apiResponse)

            // Dispatch the result
            response?.apply {
                when {
                    status.isSuccessful() -> setValue(this)
                    else -> setValue(Resource.error(errorMessage))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @MainThread
    private fun setValue(newValue: Resource<RequestType>) {
        if (result.value != newValue) result.value = newValue
    }

    fun asLiveData(): LiveData<Resource<RequestType>> {
        return result
    }

    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun createCall(): LiveData<Resource<RequestType>>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This for database operation only in case you needed it (with kotlin coroutine

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData

/**
 * A generic class that can provide a resource backed by the sqlite database.
 *
 *
 * @param <ResultType>
</ResultType> */
abstract class DatabaseResource<ResultType> {

    private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>>()

     init {
         result.value = Resource.loading(null)
         GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
         val dbSource = performDbOperation()
         GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            result.addSource(dbSource) { data ->
                result.removeSource(dbSource)
                result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                    setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                }
              }
            }
         }
     }

    private fun setValue(newValue: Resource<ResultType>) {
        if (result.value != newValue) {
            result.value = newValue
        }
    }

    fun asLiveData() = result as LiveData<Resource<ResultType>>

    protected abstract fun performDbOperation(): LiveData<ResultType>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For future Kotlin users, make it simple as:

**1. Resource class:**

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val error: Throwable? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(throwable: Throwable, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, throwable)
}
```

**2. NetworkBoundResource:**

```
inline fun <T> networkBoundResource(
    crossinline fetch : suspend () -> Response<T>
) = flow {

    emit(Resource.Loading(null))

    try {
        emit(Resource.Success(fetch().body()))
    }catch(throwable : Throwable){
        emit(Resource.Error(throwable, null))
    }
}
```